Read information in different UDS sessions
Sometimes, I faced an issue that when I read out information such as ECU software or hardware information in default session and programming session, the result was not the same. Does such information save in different memory address for each session?

This is up to the vendor's implementation, there are no strict guidelines. Although somewhat unusual, it's perfectly possible that the ECU reports e.g., different serial numbers, since diagnostic sessions may be implemented  by different software components.
